# ERROR in src/app/products/product-list.component.ts(1,2): error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: angular

Please help anyone I am getting error I m new to angular

> ERROR in src/app/products/product-list.component.ts(1,2): error TS1109: Expression expected.

## Product list component.ts

```
@import { Component } from '@angular/cord';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
})

export class productListComponent {

}
```

Comment: `@angular/cord`? Really? https://angular.io/api/core

Comment: And why `@import`? It's just `import`. Why don't you respect the naming conventions, and use the CLI to generate this code (which would then be correct, and respect naming conventions?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error with you import.
You should do this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```